# Formatting datalist display

Tags: asp.net, css, datalist

I am having problems to format datalist in an appropriate way. I have got an  whose width is set to 733px, What I want is to to display the datalist within that width , if the item is exceeding the width it should go to next line, currently it is going out of the width ....., How can i control the datalist to show for instance 4 per line then go to next line. I have used RepeatDirection="Horizontal" in my datalist.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look onto [`DataList.RepeatColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatcolumns.aspx) property:

```
DataList1.RepeatColumns = 4;
DataList1.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
```

Comment: what if I want to add a dotted line after each line of 4 items

Comment: @Muhammad Awais, e.g. add an additional block to the end of `<ItemTemplate>` for this: `<%# Container.ItemIndex % 4 == 3 ? Server.HtmlEncode("<hr />") : string.Empty %></ItemTemplate>` or use a similar construction in the `<SeparatorTemplate>`.

Comment: what i did , added a item-style sheet and added a class .datalist
{
    border-style: none none dotted none;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #C0C0C0;
   
}